Global minimal discriminants of elliptic curves and Galois representations
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\Delta$ be the global minimal discriminant. By A. Wiles et al. $E$ is modular so that there is a corresponding modular form $f$. I am wondering if the invariant $\Delta$ appears in the context of $f$. Anything would be helpful for me. Literature, result, reference etc.

$\Delta$ can't really be said to appear in the context of $f$ - in fact two elliptic curves associated to the same modular form can have different discriminants (e.g. https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/11/a/2 and https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/11/a/3). However one can always give a lower bound for $\Delta$ in terms of $f$ (e.g. the conductor, but there are sharper lower bounds as well).

To add to Will's comment, the modular form $f$ only picks out the isogeny class of $E$, not the isomorphism class.  Then $f$ determines the conductor $N$ of $E$, which places local restrictions on $\Delta$ (e.g., you know the set of primes dividing $\Delta$).  Look up discriminant-conductor relations.
